# javascript refresh self only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, reload

jquery mobile page does not work when clicking prev button in android.
So I searched a lot but I didn't find any results.
So I want to redirect the self page on the first time only.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   window.location.reload();
   //.. 
}
```

In that code, the page is reloading forever..
How can I reload the page only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use local storage. make counter true if page is loaded once.

check this out

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(!localStorage.counter) {
       window.location.reload();
       //.. 
       localStorage.counter = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd only add that it might be best to have a fallback to use cookies in case localstorage isn't supported (Modernizr's great for that.)  There's also the possibility of a clod like me who disables all localstorage on her mobile devices but allows non-third-party cookies.  BUT this does work and helped me a great deal just now :D

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code, it seems to be reloading the page as soon as the document is ready... so it's in an infinite loop.

you need to add an interval counter to set a delay.

something like

```
setInterval(
    function () {
        var url = '#';
        $('body').load(url); 
    }, 300000)
```

where 300,000 mS is 5 minutes. that's not platform specific.